# remove white space before delimiter with sed

Tags: sed, libreoffice-calc

I have data of the following format that I want to input into LibreOffice Calc:

```
data | num | num | num | num
```

For some reason LibreOffice does not think the string "3214 " is a number by default (trailing white space).

I want to replace `(\s)*|` with `|`, where `\s` stands for space and `*` for the Kleene star operation. And do this at multiple places in each line (all matches).

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/(\s)*|/|/' DataStats0914.txt
```

But it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is another way to phrase this to just delete all whitespace? In that case, just a comment on the right tool for the right job: `tr -d ' ' < DataStats0914.txt > DataStats0914.txt.modified`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
sed 's/ *|/|/g'
```